# "Send directions to your phone" Missing Cell Number for Text Message

Tags: google-maps, accounts, maps

Where did the option to send directions as a text message go? And how do I get it back?

Last month, when using "Send directions to your phone", I was presented with the options:

1. samsung SM-A326U1
2. Email to myaccount@mydomain.com
3. Text to nnn-nnn-nnnn

The text option has vanished. How do I get it back?

https://myaccount.google.com/phone DOES show my phone number

There's a hyperlink to "Connect a device".

- It says to "sign in on your computer" -- Done, as myaccount@mydomain.com.
- It says to "Sign in on your phone or tablet: Open the Google Maps app. Then tap your profile picture or initial". -- Done.  Same email address/account.
- It indicates that I should tap "Sign in to your account"

There is no "Sign in to your account", and I'm already signed in.

I really prefer sending directions via text. How do I get that option back?

Comment: It seems like this question is about Google Maps web site and thus unrelated to Android. I also see no possibility to send directions via text or SMS. Most likely the "Text to nnn-nnn-nnnn" does no longer appear because Google has removed it (may be it was misused to send spam messages or for a different reason only Google knows).